# Nested "Redirect" in React-Router-DOM

Tags: reactjs, redirect, rendering, react-router-dom

I'm new to React JS and now I'm trying to learn how to use "react-router-dom". Here I have a very simple app and I'm trying to fix one issue. So, there are 4 pages (Main Page / First Page / Second Page / **Third Page wih Items** ). *We can ignore the first 3 pages and focus on the last one - **Third Page wih Items**.* There we have 3 items. I used `<Redirect />` to make **First Item** content visible immediately after users click on **Third Page wih Items**  and it seems to work fine but there is a problem... First time you click on **Third Page wih Items**, **First Item** is shown as expected. But if you are still inside **Third Page wih Items** and you click on it again, **First Item** disappears and you basically need to reload the page or go to another page and back.

My question is - What should I do make **First Item** stays even if users click on **Third Page wih Items** multiple times in a row?

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, NavLink, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/">Main Page</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/first">First Page</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/second">Second Page</NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/third-with-items">Third Page wih Items</NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};

const Main = () => <h1>Main Page</h1>;

const First = () => {
  return <h3>First Page Content</h3>;
};
const Second = () => {
  return <h3>Second Page Content</h3>;
};
const Third = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>Third Page Content</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/third-with-items/item1">First Item</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/third-with-items/item2">Second Item</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to="/third-with-items/item3">Third Item</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <Redirect to="/third-with-items/item1" />
      <Route path="/third-with-items/item1" component={FirstItem} />
      <Route path="/third-with-items/item2" component={SecondItem} />
      <Route path="/third-with-items/item3" component={ThirdItem} />
    </div>
  );
};

const FirstItem = () => (
  <div>This text should be shown after you click "Third Page with Items"</div>
);
const SecondItem = () => <div>Something...</div>;
const ThirdItem = () => <div>Another something...</div>;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
      <Route path="/first" component={First} />
      <Route path="/second" component={Second} />
      <Route path="/third-with-items" component={Third} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```js
<Redirect to="/third-with-items/item1" />
```

with:

```js
<Route exact path="/third-with-items" component={FirstItem} />
```

The [React Router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting) shows an example of nesting routes that may help you improve your component:

```js
import {BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink, Switch, useRouteMatch} from "react-router-dom";

const Third = () => {
  let { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>Third Page Content</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <NavLink to={`${url}/item1`}>First Item</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to={`${url}/item2`}>Second Item</NavLink>
          </li>
          <li>
            <NavLink to={`${url}/item3`}>Third Item</NavLink>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path} component={FirstItem} />
        <Route path={`${path}/item1`} component={FirstItem} />
        <Route path={`${path}/item2`} component={SecondItem} />
        <Route path={`${path}/item3`} component={ThirdItem} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};
```